# Liferay: How can I hide signup page to signin users. Only display to guest?

Tags: java, jsp, liferay, portal

Any idea how can I do this, in which file or code.  I want changes.

Please help how to hide **SignUP** from navigation menu when user login.

Comment: Be specific regarding what all you know and what all you tried. If possible post your code.